# In polynomial long division, what happens when the lead terms' coefficients don't divide each other?

Tags: polynomials

I'm currently tasked with acquiring polynomial long division. So far, all examples make sense. However, what happens in a situation like $(3x^3 + 2x^2 - 3) \div (2x^2 + 1)$?
To my knowledge, iterating once would yield as an interim step:
$(3x^3 + 2x^2 - 3) - (2x^3 + x) = x^2 + 2x^2 - x - 3$
But now, we've advanced no further in reducing the polynomial!

The only solution I can see is using non-integer coefficients. Is this how a situation like this is meant to be dealt with?

(Sorry for formatting this like it's not long division. I'm talking about the long division of polynomials.)

Comment: Yes, this is the way.

Comment: Yes, you have to perform the division in $\mathbf Q[X]$.

Comment: So $\frac{3}{2}x + \text{ the rest}$?

Comment: $$  \left(  3 x^{3}  + 2 x^{2}  - 3 \right)  =  \left(  2 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  + 2 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 3 x  - 8 }{ 2 }  \right)  $$

Comment: I mean long polynomial division

Comment: The ring $\Bbb Z[X]$ doesn’t have Euclidean division, but $\Bbb Q[X]$ does. That’s the long and short of it.